# How do I access a sub-element when using $(this) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click', '.mydiv', function(){
        console.log(??????);
    });

});
```

I also have the corresponding html

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <p>Hello from inside a mydiv</p>
</div>
<div class="mydiv">
    <p>Hello from inside some other mydiv</p>
</div>
```

My goal is to print the text inside the p tags to the console when the I click on any div with the class of mydiv.  I know that this means I should be using the $(this) operator, but when I do that I am unsure of how to then access its sub elements.

I know if I were using id's (or if I only had one of these class objects) I could simply do `$('#mydiv p').val()`, but I'm unsure of how to achieve this when I'm using $(this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$('p',this)` or `$(this).find('p')` to get p tag element in `this` context:

```
$(document).on('click', '.mydiv', function(){
    console.log($('p',this).text());
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ppqtnt25/)**

Comment: You beat him to the punch maybe?

Comment: @xcdemon05 Wasn't me, my points haven't gone down any. Thanks for insinuating though...

Comment: @ahrim Lol I wasn't accusing you.  I'm saying maybe somebody wanted to give the answer that Milind and rather contribute to the community anyways he/she decided downvoting him was the only solution.

Comment: @xcdemon05 Odd how you could get all that from your statement, when most would determine your statement to be indicative of the former. This is even reinforced by your necessity to laugh it off. Clearly you felt the need to make a funny comment which you are now trying to deny...

Comment: @ahrim Note that it is you who got bent out of shape over a comment that wasn't even about you.  How can you read "You beat him to the punch maybe?" and think "He must be talking about me!!!"? when there are thousands of other users?  Someone downvoted him.  I just was saying maybe that person was upset that he answered before they could.

Comment: @xcdemon05 hrmm, could it be because his answer was 5 seconds faster than mine? "beat him to the punch", yea, common sense will tell you that... it was a clear referral.

Answer (score 2):

Using `$(this)` and jQuery's `.find()` you can get the child elements that you choose:

```
console.log($(this).find('p').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to go about this. One of the ways has been mentioned here by others (the `find` method). The problem with the find method is that it finds all elements inside your div and not the direct children. So, if you have elements that are nested another level, it gets that as well.

With the `children` method, it will find the direct child of the element, but not anything nested deeper.

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <div>
        <p>Nested p</p>
    </div>
</div>

$('.mydiv').find('p'); // Finds this element, but children() will not
```

Versus

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <p>
        Direct p
    </p>
 </div>

 $('.mydiv').children('p'); // Will find this element, but find() will as well
```

With the `find` method, you will find the one nested inside the second div, whilst with the `children` method, you will find only the direct child.

Depending on your needs, you may use `find` or `children`